# Moving Hosts: Freeform 2.6.6 not sending email

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, ee1

I'm moving one of my sites to a new host. I'm still using EE 1.6.9 and using it with Freeform 2.6.6. I know, I know... I'm way out of date. But, things have worked and I've never seen a need up upgrade my software and pay for latest and greatest.

So... I'm hoping someone can give me some things to try because I'm all out of ideas.

I'm operating the site under a test URL for the time being just to ensure everything works. I've changed all paths (that I know of), changed config.php file, updated permissions on the necessary files/folders on the server, etc. The ONLY thing I can't seem to get working is getting Freeform to send email. On my current live host, I've used this version of EE and Freeform together for probably four years with zero issues sending mail.

On my new host, the only difference that I can tell is that I'm now using PHP 5.2, where on my old (current) host they're still using PHP 5.1.6. I don't think this would make a huge difference, but maybe? I'm not sure I can downgrade to 5.1.6, so if that is in fact an issue, is there an updated Freeform that I could install that will still work with my version of EE and PHP 5.2?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks all

EDIT:

I wanted to add that on my old (current) host, email configuration was setup to use phpmail. On the new host, they use sendmail for email. So, I have went in and changed the email configuration in Admin to "sendmail."

I'm also able to email myself via the "communicate" tab in the control panel, so I know email is working.

Comment: I wanted to post a comment update. I went ahead and completely uninstalled Freeform from my test site and re-installed it using the default_template and a couple test fields. It worked fine. So, now I'm going through the process of rebuilding my fields and templates and we'll see what happens!

Comment: So after my last comment I re-installed everything and it worked fine until I started adding my own fields and custom templates back in. So I deleted it all again and installed the newest version of FreeForm for EE1.6.8 which is FreeForm 3.x. I got it all installed and working with the default fields and default_template then tried my own custom template and it worked fine about 10 times. I had to leave the house for a while and came back to it no longer working. If I use the default_template, it works every time. If i change to my own custom template, it seems to no longer work. Ideas?

Comment: Sorry for all of the updates. I believe I've narrowed down the issue that's causing my custom templates to not work with FreeForm. I have created a "contact" template and in the "From Email" field I've used the {email} variable so that when the form is submitted, the "From" field uses whatever email the user submitted in the "email" field of the form. This way I can simply reply to the email and respond if needed. Using {email} in the template makes the email not send. If I replace {email} with something like info@domain.com then the email sends every time. Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: - Can you tell us what **exact** version number of Freeform 3.x that you are using? 
- Have you created a Freeform custom field named "email"?
- Can you show your template code? Please keep in mind that you should use the Freeform 3.x nomenclature in your particular case (not the Freeform 4.x nomenclature)

Comment: Hi. I got this sorted out (answered my own question below). But I'm using 3.1.5.

Answer (score 2):

Just a follow up in case anyone else is having this problem. It ended up being my new host. I was with EngineHosting and was able to use a variable like `{email}` in the FreeForm template for the "From Email." This would allow the email to appear to have been sent from the person contacting me. Turns out, my new host does not allow that. So, I had to add a couple more tags to my FreeForm form for reply-to headers. To do that, you need three more tags:

- `reply_to`
- `reply_to_email_field`
- `reply_to_name_field`

`reply_to` would be set to `yes` and then you can set `reply_to_email_field` to `{email}` (or whatever the input name is in your form) and `reply_to_name_field` to something like `{name}` or whatever your name field is called in your form.

Hope that helps.